# Reading resources from eclipse and a runable jar

Tags: java, spring, classloader, executable-jar

I'm trying to read files in a directory from the runnable jar, but the follwing code works only in eclipse, however, it doesnt work in the running jar using java command

````
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePatternResolver;
public class mmm {
    
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        mmm mmm1=new mmm();
        ClassLoader classLoader = mmm1.getClass().getClassLoader();
         String locationPattern = "classpath*:/cc/ff/rr/tttt**";  // tttt is a resource folder contains 2 files nn.txt ,ss.txt 
         ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver( );
         //Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources(locationPattern);
         Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources(locationPattern);  ======> 
         System.out.println("Number of files "+resources.length);
         for (Resource resource : resources) {
        System.out.println("file :"+resource.getFilename());
             
}```

in java commande line i'm getting the follwing error  

'''
java.io.FileNotFoundException: URL [rsrc:cc/ff/rr/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: rsrc:cc/ff/rr/
        at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:204)
        at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:52)
        at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getFile(UrlResource.java:168)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.doFindPathMatchingFileResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:528)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.findPathMatchingResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:349)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.getResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:267)
        at cc.ff.rr.mmm.main(mmm.java:36)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:61)'''

Please, what is the issue with the code?
````

Comment: what java command you use to run it? Have you specify the classpath? I think you should specify it

Comment: Yes, I have specified the classpath, but nothing happens .

Answer (score 0):

Since the code works very well in eclipse, but it fails with java command as .jar file. I have changed some configuration during the export process (export as runnable jar) and it works for me:
[image]

So, Both the first and the last options in "**Library handling:**" work, except the second one, this the only change that makes difference.